# Firebase rules to give access to a path based on email address

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm writing an app where it should be possible to invite users to a family. Once the user accepts they become members.

The data looks like this:

```js
families: {
   familyKey1: {
      name: "First Family Name"
   },
   familyKey2: {
      name: "Second Family Name"
   },
},
invites: {
   inviteKey1: {
      familyKey: "familyKey1",
      email: "user@domain.tld"
   }
},
users: {
   uid1: {
      familyKey: "familyKey2"
   }
}
```

I want a logged in user to be able to access the `/families/familyKeyX/` path if:

1. **familyKeyX** exists `/users/uidX/` for the currently logged in user.
2. There is an invite under `/invites/inviteKeyX/` where the email matches the currently logged in user and the invite contains **familyKeyX**

The first part works fine by creating a rule as follows:

```js
"families": {
   "$familyKey": {
      ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('familyKey').val() == $familyKey"
   }
}
```

The second part however I cannot get to work. It could have been set up the same way if I could post the email as part of the path to the object but firebase does not allow the `@` sign so I had to generate the `inviteKey`. But that key is unknown when I write the rule and firebase doesn't allow searches or wildcards on the rule path.

I was thinking of making the path `{"invites": { "familyKeyX": { "email": "user@domain.tld"} } }`. But that is a no-go since it only allows for one invite per family. There could be multiple users with different emails with pending invites. As soon I introduce a unique key to form a list of invites I don't know the path to write the rule...

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firebase security rules you can read/check data at a known path in the database. You cannot however search for data under a specific path in the database.

So while in code you could do:

```
root.child("invites").orderBy("email").equalTo("user@domain.tld")
```

The equivalent to this query is **not** possible in security rules.

---

In order to be able to look up whether a given email has access to the family, you will need to store the email address of the user as a key in a separate map. Since `.` is not allowed inside a key, you'll have to encode that - typically by replacing it with a `,` which *is* allowed in a key and conveniently cannot appear in an email address.

So:

```
emailToInvites: {
   "user@domain,tld": {
      "familyKey1": "inviteKey1"
   }
},
```

Now with this in place, you can [replace `.` with `,`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#replacesubstring_replacement) in the email address and then use that to look up if an invite exists under `emailToInvites`.